# set element fit into container in panzoom.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery.panzoom

I wanted to use panzoom.js. My image size is larger than container. I needed to make it fit into the container by default view.

```
<div class="container">
    <img id="panzoom" src="http://blog.millermedeiros.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/awesome_tiger.svg" width="900" height="900">
</div>
```

Here the jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/Vipin/qam85n47/

Please help me to get it.

I have tried with "startTransform" value. But I needed it dynamically.

It should be calculated dynamically.

Image and container size might be changed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
    //get parent width height
    var w = $(".container").width();
    var h = $(".container").height();
    //set parent width height to panzoom element
    $("#panzoom").width(w)
    $("#panzoom").height(h)
    $("#panzoom").panzoom();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/vfqdnm8d/2/

Comment: I can't change the size of element. I needed to change the zoom level.

like "startTransform".

Element height is given from server. Can't be changed it. Could be adjusted zoom level.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to approach it in this way:

```
<div class="container">
    <img width="900" height="900" id="panzoom" src="http://blog.millermedeiros.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/awesome_tiger.svg" />
</div>

.container img {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
}
```

Setting the image width to `100%`, dynamic and accounts for changes in image size and container size

https://jsfiddle.net/qam85n47/11/

Comment: I can't change the size of element. I needed to change the zoom level. like "startTransform". Element height is given from server. Can't be changed it. Could be adjusted zoom level

Comment: Might not be sure exactly what you mean. But reading from your first scentence "I needed to make it fit into the container by default view.". My adjusted answer could work.

Comment: I needed something like this

https://jsfiddle.net/Vipin/fcc3ap0y/2/

I am not able to chage the size of image.

Here, If I remove this code: $('#wrap').css('-webkit-transform', ' scale(' + 0.745 + ')');

It will change to actual size.